# $n$th derivative of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: derivatives, recurrence-relations

I observed that 
$f^{(n)}(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-x^2} & \text{if $n=0$}\\
-2xe^{-x^2} & \text{if $n=1$}\\
f^{(n-1)}(x)-f^{(n-2)}(x) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$
How to get the closed form?
**Edit:** This recurrence does not hold.

Comment: How did you find this recurrence relation ?

Comment: I guessed it and proved by induction. Is it wrong?

Comment: I think it is wrong. $f^{(2)}(x)=-2e^{-x^2}+(-2x)^2e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Did you try to validate it by applying it to $f^{(2)}$ ? I think it is not equal to $f^{(1)} - f^{(0)} $

Comment: I don't think that recurrence is true, since that would mean that $f^{(n)}(x)=(a_nx+b_n))f(x)$ for some $a_n,b_n$, and that is not the case- $f^{(2)}(x)=(4x^2-2)e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: To obtain the right recurrence, write $f^{(n)}(x)=e^{-x^2}P_n(x)$ where $P_n$ is a sequence of polynomials.

We get $f^{n+1}(x)=e^{-x^2}(P_n'(x)-2xP_n(x))$, hence $P_{n+1}(x)=P_n'(x)-2xP_n(x)$. There may be a nice closed form for the coefficients of $P_n$, consider the similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702. (I just deleted my answer because I thought it would better be a comment.)

Comment: @barto You could've left it as it was. I'm trying to find the sequence, it seems that the coefficent of the highest order of $n$th polynomial is $2^n$, except the first one.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2/193914#193914).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the recursion $f_n=f_{n-1}-f_{n-2}$ always has a solution of the form

$$
C_1(1/2+i\sqrt{3}/2)^n  + C_2(1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2)^n,
$$

with $C_1,C_2$ constants to be determined from the initial values $f_0,f_1$.

**Edit:** Your recurrence does not hold.

Comment: He mentioned that the $n$-th derivatives obey a certain recurrence formula, with $f_n = D^n(e^{-x^2})$. Thus $f_n$ would be a legitimate sequence (of functions). But the point is moot anyway, since the recurrence he derived turns out to be incorrect.

Comment: Why not? The recurrence holds for every $x$ separately, and only the initial values explicitly depend on $x$. Example: $f_n(x)=2f_{n-1}(x)$, with $f_0(x)=x$. Then $f_n=2^nx=f_n(x)$.

Comment: I mean you cannot solve it that way unless you have had enough caffeine.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the recurrence relation holds then the $n$-th derivative is a telescopic sum

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered here:

- [Hermite polynomials recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581897/hermite-polynomials-recurrence-relation)

More informatiion at:

- [Hermite polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitePolynomial.html)

The keywords are "Hermite polynomial" and "Rodrigues formula".